# cannot run two application deployed on websphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, websphere-portal

I need help, since I am new to websphere.
We have 2 applications,  deployed in the same websphere server. The problem is that we cannot run those 2 applications simultaneously. Running the 2nd application will immediately expire the 1st application (the 2nd application will also expire after a few seconds) .

Here are the series of events

- Login to the 1st application    http: //stackoverflow:8080/Application1URL/
- Leave the application 1 gui running (you must be logged into the application).
- Open another browser tab. Run the 2nd application on the new tab:   http: //stackoverflow:8080/Application2URL/
- You will notice that the application1 session will immediately expire (“Session Expired. Please login again.”). This happens as soon as the application2 login screen appears
- If you try to login back into application1 you will get a message saying the user is already logged in (“User is already logged in. Do you want to force logout the other session ?”)

Kindly suggest any ideas to debug the issue.

Comment: Some clarification questions: Do you have application security turned on and use JEE security or some custom solution? Ensure that you are using LTPA authentication mechanism and have SSO enabled.

Comment: Until you are able to debug issue using the IE browser, can you try File > New Session. That should let you run two apps at once.

Comment: SSO is enabled, and this Issue is seen on IE and firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your applications probably invalidate sessions for each other. For example they are looking for some attribute in the session and if it is not found they invalidate session. Since same sessionId is shared by default across applications, once the second app invalidate the session the id is changed and first app cannot find its session any more.

Go to one of your applications and change session cookie name to something different.

- In web admin console click `Enterprise Applications > yourApp > Session management`
- Check `Override session management` and click `Apply` and `Save`
- Click `Enable cookies` link, and change default cookie name to something custom. Click `OK` and `Save` changes
- Restart application.

Your applications shouldn't logout each other anymore.